# Unable to reduce Blender file size for render farms?

Tags: animation, cycles-render-engine, texturing, blend-files, blender-id

I'm hitting a wall here.
I have a 185-frames-long animation that I want to send to SheepIt for rendering but no matter what I do the file size stays around 1,5-1,8GB and the upload limit on SheepIt is 500MB..

I've tried reducing all my textures to 2K, baking the animations, applying all modifiers (except particle emitters), purging all orphaned data-blocks.. but the blend file size stays exactly the same, for some reason it's even bigger now.

I really don't know what to do here, can anyone help ?
I would really appreciate that, I'm stuck as hell.
Thanks !

[image: Text]

Full picture : https://i.postimg.cc/T1xRdZXq/Blender-Project.png

Comment: Are you able to upload the unmodified version of the file?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the Outliner to Blender File mode and go through all the data saved in the file to see if you have something not needed there or maybe duplicates:
[image]

You should not apply modifiers since procedural stuff will take less space. Same might be true for baking animation. I would recommend to test it. Generally you might want to do calculations during render instead of pre-calculating and saving the results to the file using space.

Other than that there is no rule that it should be possible to render any kind of project on SheepIt. It might just not be possible and you will need to search for another render farm with less restrictions or other rendering solution.

Comment: Good answer, blender is not great at finding orphaned data blocks sometimes.  It's likely the old texture images are sitting there.  Maybe open in some UV image editor somewhere.

Comment: There may be duplicates as well for example if one pastes some objects copied from another scene, new materials are created even if same materials already exist in the file.